# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Lexer object

Tags: python, typeerror

I tried to make an lexer in python with replit because I wanted to try making my own programming language. When I tested it out with the half of the lexer working, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 77, in <module>
    out, error = Lexer(data)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Lexer object
```

I've never seen this error before and I don't understand it.
This is my code:

```
TT_NUM = "Number"
TT_ADD = "Add"
TT_SUB = "Subtract"
TT_MUL = "Multiply"
TT_DIV = "Divide"
TT_STR = "String"
TT_DOT = "Dot"
TT_WS = "Whitespace"
TT_NL = "New Line"
TT_COLON = "Colon"

strs = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_"
nums = "1234567890"
add = "+"
sub = "-"
mul = "*"
div = "/"
dot = "."
ws = " "
nl = "\n"


class Lexer:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.pos = 1
        self.column = 1
        self.row = 1
        self.tokens = []
        self.currentchar = ""
        self.tokenize()

    def tokenize(self):
        result = ""
        token = ""
        out = []
        while self.pos <= len(self.data):
            self.currentchar = self.data[self.pos|self.pos]
            if self.currentchar in nums:
                result += self.currentchar
                if result[1|1] not in strs:
                    token = TT_NUM
                self.pos += 1
                self.column += 1
            elif self.currentchar == add:
                result += self.currentchar
                token = TT_ADD
                self.pos += 1
                self.column += 1
            elif self.currentchar == sub:
                result += self.currentchar
                token = TT_SUB
                self.pos += 1
                self.column += 1
            elif self.currentchar == mul:
                result += self.currentchar
                token = TT_MUL
                self.pos += 1
                self.column += 1
            elif self.currentchar == div:
                result += self.currentchar
                token = TT_DIV
                self.pos += 1
                self.column += 1
            elif self.currentchar == dot:
                out.append(token)
                out.append(result)
                result = self.currentchar
                token = TT_DOT
                self.pos += 1
                self.column += 1
            else:
                return None, "Invalid Character '" + self.currentchar + "' at line " + str(self.row) + ", column " + str(self.column)
            if self.pos > 1:
                return out, None
data = "test"
out, error = Lexer(data)
if error:
    print("Traceback (most recent call last):\n" + error)
```

What happend that there is that error? How can I fix this?

Comment: As the error suggests, you can't split `Lexer` into 2 elements. If you want to make it iterable, you'll need to implement `__iter__` and `__next__` in that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called a ctor in this way:

```
out, error = Lexer(data)
```

This is a perfectly nice idiom used in Lua, Go, and also when calling python methods such as:

```
out, error = MyLexer(data).parse()
```

But as written, you just called the constructor, not a method.
With a method like `.parse()` you could make up a `return` signature any way you like, including `return out, error` 2-tuple which would unpack nicely.
In python, the `__init__()` result you get from a call like `Lexer( ... )` will typically be a single object, not a tuple.

Perhaps you would like to make your lexer conform to the iterable protocol?
You would need to implement methods like [`__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) and [`__next__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) for that to work properly.
The OP code is definitely not attempting to implement
the iterable protocol.

---

Passing around an error status can be a good approach.
An alternate API design to consider,
one that is more pythonic,
would be to `raise` ValueError or an app-specific error
upon encountering parse fail.

---

EDIT

On closer examination, it appears you came very close
to implementing the design you had in mind.
The tokenizer returns two items.
You just never called that method.

```
out, error = Lexer(data).tokenizer()

print(out, error)
```

Also, rather than returning a giant list,
consider `yield`ing items one at a time,
with `raise ValueError()` for an unrecognized character.

For TT_COLON and similar, consider changing them
from `str` to `Enum`.
Then you'll have an opportunity to tack other attributes
onto them, such as valid characters: '*', ':', 'a..z', maybe re.compile(r'[a-z]').

Comment: Yes, I would like to do that. But I've never heared of these methots, I don't know what they do and I don't know how to implement these. Could you maybe help me do that?

Comment: now i have the problem: i dont get any output